# inline block grid system - css won't apply to dynamically created element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a inline -block grid system, I want to do something like add re-order the element and add it back to the grid. The js part is ok, how ever when the element added back, it won't apply the css. I made a simple case to show you the error

Open the link and try clicking show error button you will see the element mess up

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<style>
#grid{
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0.1px;
}

#grid .item{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

#grid:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#grid .placeholder{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
}
</style>

<script>
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var item = $('#grid').children('.item');
            item.prependTo('#grid');
    });

});
</script>

<div id="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
<button>show the error</button>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ap0ksy8/2/

Screen shots

[image]

[image]

Comment: specifically, the `text-align: justify` isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a whitespace problem!

When you run your script, it will 'refresh' the HTML without whitespace.

You should remove **all** whitespaces so it will look like the errored version. After that, you have to set a margin to the left and right, so that it always looks good.

Your code (with Javascript):

```css
#grid{
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0.1px;
}

#grid .item{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
}

#grid:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#grid .placeholder{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
  <div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
```

Without whitespace, using margin + Javascript:

```js
$(function(){
 $('button').click(function(){
  var item = $('#grid').children('.item');
   item.prependTo('#grid');
 });
 
});
```

```css
#grid{
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 0.1px;
}

#grid .item{
  display: inline-block;
  background: #eee;
  width: 23%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 2.5%;
  /*added margin*/
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#grid:after{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

#grid .placeholder{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 23%;
  /*added margin*/
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="grid">
  <div class="item"></div><--
  --><div class="item"></div><--
  --><div class="item"></div><--
  --><div class="item"></div><--
  --><div class="item"></div><--
  --><div class="item"></div><--
  --><div class="placeholder"></div><--
  --><div class="placeholder"></div>
</div>
<button>show the error</button>
```

Obviously, the best solution is to actually fix your CSS to avoid this kind of ugly 'hack'.

Comment: cool. Thanks, so white space is culprit. For that I fix it by adding white space where it lost.

Comment: @angry_kiwi No, the idea is to **remove** the whitespace and add a margin. Or change the CSS.

Comment: I fixed it by adding white space. Adding margin will require more work, which will be against the point of using grid system.

Comment: @angry_kiwi Actually, grid systems use margins and percent-based widths. Some may use a fixed width, like [960-grid](http://960.gs/demo.html). But it still uses margins.

Comment: not with this grid. add margin to the item will break the layout.

Comment: @angry_kiwi Even without whitespace?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        var item = $('#grid').children('.item');
            item.prependTo('#grid');
            $('.item').after(" "); // add white space
    });

});
```

the white space added will compensate for the white space trimmed by jquery